# Using same view for multiple hierarchy within the same dimension in mondrian

Tags: mdx, pentaho, mondrian

I have defined a schema. I am repeating the definition of the same view in each hierarchy within a dimension. Is there a way I could define the view for dimension instead of each hierarchy in a dimension ?

```
<Schema name="shop_cube">
  <Dimension name="Product dimensions">
    <Hierarchy name="gtin" hasAll="true" primaryKey="id">
      <View alias="&quot;product_dimension&quot;"> 
         <SQL dialect="generic"> 
            <![CDATA[SELECT * FROM product_dimension where name="my_shop"]]> 
         </SQL> 
      </View>
      <Level name="gtin" column="product_gtin" type="String" hideMemberIf="IfBlankName" uniqueMembers="false">
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>

    <Hierarchy name="Productgroup" hasAll="true" primaryKey="id">
      <View alias="&quot;product_dimension&quot;"> 
        <SQL dialect="generic"> 
          <![CDATA[SELECT * FROM product_dimension where name="my_shop"]]> 
        </SQL> 
      </View>
      <Level name="Productgroup" column="product_group" type="String" hideMemberIf="IfBlankName" uniqueMembers="false">
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
 </Dimension>
  ...
  ...
 <DimensionUsage name="Product dimensions" source="Product dimensions" foreignKey="product_dimension_id"/>
</Schema>
```